# Determining whether a critical point is max,min or saddle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Consider $f(x,y,z)=x^2+7y^2-2xy+6yz+2y^3+3z^2$. Show the origin is a critical point and classify the critical point as local min, local max or a saddle point.

I think I've shown that the origin is a critcal point by finding the $\nabla f(x,y,z)=(2x-2y,14y-2x+6z+6y^2,6y+6z)=\vec{0}$ gives the 3 equations:

$2x-2y=0\implies x=y$

$14y-2x+6z+6y^2=0$

and

$6y+6z=0\implies y=-z$

But I'm not too sure how to continue from this point.

EDIT:

I tried to find the eigenvalues of the Hessian, but I am having trouble finding the eigenvalues. I got the characteristic polynomial as:

$144-\lambda^3+30\lambda^2-124\lambda-12\lambda^2 y-96\lambda y+ 144y$

which I have no idea how to even begin to factor to get my eigenvalues. Is there some sort of shortcut I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't think I understand why your $f$ takes $w$ as an argument and then doesn't use it. Doing so makes this problem a bit weird because $(0,0,0,w)$ will be a critical point for all $w$.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. There shouldn't be a $w$ there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You also have a $w$ in $\nabla f$. Anyway, now you should use the second derivative test. Do you know about eigenvalues? (There is a way to answer the question without eigenvalues, but it is not so obvious why it works.)

Comment: By Second Derivative Test, you mean checking the determinant of the Hessian of $f$? Yes, I know about eigenvalues.

Comment: OK. The point is a local max if all eigenvalues of the Hessian are negative, a local min if all eigenvalues of the Hessian are positive, and a saddle point if some eigenvalues of the Hessian are positive and others are negative. If all are nonnegative but some are zero or all are nonpositive but some are zero, then the second derivative test doesn't help.

Comment: In 2D one can detect all of this using just the trace and the determinant (which is the usual thing taught in multivar calc). In 3D and higher this is no longer true: for instance the eigenvalues could be $-1,-2,10$, in which case the trace will be $7$ and the determinant will be $20$ (both positive) but the point is a saddle point anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I can prove that the point is a minimum, the proof that I have is not really at your level. The proof that I have is the following: the Hessian at the origin is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 14 & 6 \\ 0 & 6 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$. By the Gerschgorin circle theorem and symmetry, it follows that one eigenvalue is in the interval $[6,22]$ and the other two are in the interval $[0,12]$. So the only thing that could be an obstruction would be a zero eigenvalue; and the determinant is nonzero, so there is not one of those.

Comment: But I do not know how to give a proof without the Gerschgorin circle theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute the hessian and determine its signature